# Wi-Pi High Latency

Tags: raspbian, wifi

Model B, Raspbian, Wi-Pi vs Macbook Pro

Setup

- Both devices are sitting right next to eachother
- Connected to the same router.
- `traceroute` is the same for both
- Even typing on the Pi via SSH feels slow

Is there any way to get the latency down?

R.Pi

```
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=185 ttl=54 time=489 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=186 ttl=54 time=718 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=187 ttl=54 time=536 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=188 ttl=54 time=563 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=190 ttl=54 time=409 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=191 ttl=54 time=429 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=192 ttl=54 time=453 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=193 ttl=54 time=476 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=194 ttl=54 time=183 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=196 ttl=54 time=344 ms
```

OS X

```
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_seq=180 ttl=54 time=182.338 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_seq=181 ttl=54 time=181.657 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_seq=182 ttl=54 time=181.700 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_seq=183 ttl=54 time=182.498 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_seq=184 ttl=54 time=181.373 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_seq=185 ttl=54 time=187.886 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_seq=186 ttl=54 time=181.224 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_seq=187 ttl=54 time=185.362 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_seq=188 ttl=54 time=180.515 ms
```

Comment: bad power supply most likley reason. the Wifi doesnot have enough juice to go full power.

Comment: @ppumkin, in hopes, I changed it to a 1A powersupply and still no luck. thanks though.

Comment: Yea... I gave up with WiFi on my Pi because I had the same problem.. but your using WiPi....? NOt sure what the problem is :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one thread where a guy had [trouble streaming at 720p with the WiPi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=22753). He overclocked it and he got a lot closer to 720.

It works.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ ping 4.2.2.1
PING 4.2.2.1 (4.2.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=54 time=179 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=54 time=177 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=54 time=251 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=4 ttl=54 time=177 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=5 ttl=54 time=177 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=6 ttl=54 time=178 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.1: icmp_req=7 ttl=54 time=178 ms
```

My settings [from here](http://megakemp.com/2013/02/26/adventures-in-overclocking-a-raspberry-pi/) in /boot/config.txt:

```
arm_freq=1000
core_freq=500
sdram_freq=500
over_voltage=6
force_turbo=0
```

These settings are safe as long as `force_turbo=0` via [here](http://hwbot.org/news/9761_raspberry_pi_overclocking_%E2%80%93_cheap_fun_and_hwbot_prime_oc_guide/), [here](http://megakemp.com/2013/02/26/adventures-in-overclocking-a-raspberry-pi/), [here](http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=10488&page=2).